# Node Express joi validation failed when I added .when()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, joi

I'm setting my schema in Mongoose model using Joi and Joigoose, everything works fine until I add the conditions " .when(...) " like following

```
const ClientJoiSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    clientType: Joi.string().valid("physical", "moral").default("physical"),
    firstName: Joi.when('clientType', { is: "physical", then: Joi.string().required() }),
    lastName: Joi.when('clientType', { is: "physical", then: Joi.string().required() }),
    ...
)}
```

when I try that on Postman I get this :

```
"message": {
        "errors": {
            "firstName": {
                "properties": {
                    "message": "Validator failed for path `firstName` with value `Daniel`",
                    "type": "user defined",
                    "path": "firstName",
                    "value": "Daniel"
                },
                "kind": "user defined",
                "path": "firstName",
                "value": "Daniel"
            },
            "lastName": {
                "properties": {
                    "message": "Validator failed for path `lastName` with value `Noah`",
                    "type": "user defined",
                    "path": "lastName",
                    "value": "Noah"
                },
                "kind": "user defined",
                "path": "lastName",
                "value": "Noah"
            }
        },
        "_message": "Clients validation failed",
        "message": "Clients validation failed: firstName: Validator failed for path `firstName` with value `Daniel`, lastName: Validator failed for path `lastName` with value `Noah`"
    }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I'll consider that, thank you for notifying !

Answer (score 0):

`Joi.object().keys({ ... })` is not a function, you should use `Joi.object({ ... })` only.

For more information, please check out [JOI Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).